# Delete first column and then take them as a index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, word2vec

I have a `word2vec` dataframe like this which saved from save_word2vec_format using Gensim under txt file. After using pandas to read this file. (Picture below). How to delete first row and make them as a index?
My txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O206N93hPSmvMjwc0W5ATyqQMdMwhRlF/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

save the row:

```
new_index = df.iloc[0]
```

drop it to avoid length mismatch:

```
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)
```

and set it:

```
df.set_index(new_index, inplace=True)
```

you will get a `SettingWithCopyWarning` but that's the most elegant solution i could come up with.

if you want to set the headers (and not the first row) do:

```
df.index = df.columns
```

Comment: No you're wrong this is my txt file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O206N93hPSmvMjwc0W5ATyqQMdMwhRlF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: wrong about what ? if you want me to view your dataframe please a paste miniaturised version of it in your question. don't send a  link or post a picture.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

to replace index as header,

```
_X_T.index=_X_T.columns
```

to replace first row as header,

```
_X_T.index=_X_T.iloc[0]
```

Comment: wouldn't he get `Length mismatch` if he replaced the index with the first row?
because he would have an extra row (the one you just set as an index)

Comment: @moshevi -  it will  work only for mXm data frame. Setting the index using first column indirectly means mXm structure.  if mXn is a dataframe then setting index by first row is meaningless

Comment: no you're wrong. this is my txt file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O206N93hPSmvMjwc0W5ATyqQMdMwhRlF/view?usp=sharing